# Node.js and Arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino, hardware, firewall, mean-stack

I am new to arduino, however I have experience in web development, lately I have been using, meteor js and the mean stack for different projects. I am open to trying any language though.

What I am trying to do is build a simple application to control the led on the arduino over the web.

I am working with another person and the arduino will be behind a firewall so I am not sure how to access it via the internet. I do have access to a arduino yun that I can use for testing at home which does have linio connected via bridge, which I dont quite understand what that does.

Ive also heard of this, https://www.yaler.net/ but would like to stay away from third party builds as much as possible if I can do it myself.

Whats the common way to do this with a arduino behind a firewall. and how do i do this with a arduino yun, is it easier with a yun?

Comment: What I read about linio it is a webserver. So you can access your arduino for the web using REST (get, post, delete, http calls). That is easily than use socket. What you need of your arduino to access it is have the ip:port and the firewall open this port. If you don't have a static ip, you can use some tools like no-ip.

Answer (score 1):

So this is kind of a vague question, because we don't know exactly what your setup is and what's up with your firewall. But I'll try to help you out.

> What I am trying to do is build a simple application to control the
>   led on the arduino over the web.

So this means you will need a web server running on the Arduino with a REST http client perhaps. You can easily find a dozen ways to do this by googling Arduino and REST, but [here](http://blog.arduino.cc/2011/04/28/restduino-arduino-hacking-for-the-rest-of-us/) is one way you might go about it. Honestly though, I really wouldn't want to set up a REST server without a library.

From there, you simply set up a REST endpoint that when called, turns on the LED.

> Whats the common way to do this with an Arduino behind a firewall.

This isn't remotely constrained to Arduinos. All (?) servers are behind a firewall. You will need to talk with your network administrator and have them open up the 80 port (for instance) and have it forward the call on the public port to the local Arduino server.

> is it easier with a yun?

It doesn't matter what Arduino board you're running. It obviously has to have an ethernet or wireless port/shield but otherwise it doesn't matter.

I shouldn't even bring up the fact that googling "arduino rest controlled led" brought [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Web-LED/) link up... Besides the firewall, that appears to be exactly what you're looking for or will at least get you going.